# How to expose Sitecore media URLs to outside world?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library

We are trying to expose Sitecore media URLs to some other application.

One of the ways I could think about is creating a Virtual Directory and linking it with physical server where images are stored.

Limitation of this approach is there won't be a way to fetch thumbnails from Virtual Directory URL.
e.g. ~/media/image.ashx?bc=White&dmc=0&h=500&thn=0&w=500 wont work with virtual directory

Is there any way to expose image URLs where we can expose actual version as well as a thumbnail of the images to other application?
e.g. exposing both ~/media/image.ashx and  ~/media/image.ashx?bc=White&dmc=0&h=500&thn=0&w=500

Comment: better to ask this question on - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not just include hostname into the url?
Do remember medias could be stored database-driven(blobs) without any file-based equivalent.
Exposing virtual directory would bring limitations at once.

Answer (score 0):

As these are images so you can append image's src property with Request.Url.Scheme +"://"+Request.Url.Host + /~/media/image.ashx?bc=White&dmc=0&h=500&thn=0&w=500